# Facebook fbml add fan button to page

Tags: facebook, facebook-fbml

I'm trying to figure out how to add a Fan button to a Facebook page right next to the company name. I've seen this done on a few pages, as shown in the following screenshot.

[image]

I've added the FBML application though I can't find a great deal of information on the code required for the actual button and then how to place the button on the page. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For pages, that button is automatically handled by Facebook. If you are already a Fan of the page, the button won't appear. You should be able to "unfan" the page in your account settings.

The FBML application lets you add arbitrary FBML to the "box" that represents that application. It has nothing to do with the Fan button.

Answer (score 0):

Visit the url that lets you edit your page information, on the right had side you should see something along the lines of "Promote with a fan box" -- that should be what you're looking for.

If you want to do it by hand you can use the fb:fan tag (http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:fan)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. Yep I delved into the hacks for this using FBML though eventually logged out and logged in with a different account and lo and behold! Facebook add this Fan Button by default now.